# Rails and Exim for Mailer with external mail provider?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, external, host, exim

we have our mail outsourced. so everything is on an external server. in my rails app i want to send email with exim, but it doesn't work, because the sender address is on another server. Any advice on this?

Thank you!